# getting error linker command failed with exit code 1 when compiling app

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to iOS and I was working through this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) (scroll down to Prototype cells ), when I tried to compile my app, i got the following error below. the first part of my question is, how can I make sense of anything in there? I have no idea how to interpret it. Can you guide me on what could be the problem?

```
Ld /Users/nadirahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prototypeCustomCellExample-dgygyvcibtndywgeapixzpvxohkj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/prototypeCustomCellExample.app/prototypeCustomCellExample normal x86_64
    cd /Users/nadirahmed/Documents/iOS/prototypeCustomCellExample
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -L/Users/nadirahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prototypeCustomCellExample-dgygyvcibtndywgeapixzpvxohkj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/nadirahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prototypeCustomCellExample-dgygyvcibtndywgeapixzpvxohkj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/nadirahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prototypeCustomCellExample-dgygyvcibtndywgeapixzpvxohkj/Build/Intermediates/prototypeCustomCellExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/prototypeCustomCellExample.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/prototypeCustomCellExample.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nadirahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prototypeCustomCellExample-dgygyvcibtndywgeapixzpvxohkj/Build/Intermediates/prototypeCustomCellExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/prototypeCustomCellExample.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/prototypeCustomCellExample_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nadirahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prototypeCustomCellExample-dgygyvcibtndywgeapixzpvxohkj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/prototypeCustomCellExample.app/prototypeCustomCellExample


duplicate symbol __players in:
    /Users/nadirahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prototypeCustomCellExample-dgygyvcibtndywgeapixzpvxohkj/Build/Intermediates/prototypeCustomCellExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/prototypeCustomCellExample.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
    /Users/nadirahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prototypeCustomCellExample-dgygyvcibtndywgeapixzpvxohkj/Build/Intermediates/prototypeCustomCellExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/prototypeCustomCellExample.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Player.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

just check:

1.Try finding in the whole project your class Player and make sure only one copy is available within your project.

```
2.You could also get this error if you mistakenly let XCode's auto-complete for #import statements specify the '.m" file for the
'duplicate' class instead of the '.h'.
```

THANKS